# How to get COLUMN_NAMES of stored procedure result set

Tags: sql-server

am getting table COLUMN_NAMES by using this query

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'CustomerTable'
```

but i want COLUMN_NAMES of stored procedure result set

```
Exec GetCustomers 'Get',4099,27
```

Comment: [`sp_describe_first_result_set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql).

Comment: Thanks Jeroen got it